# Free Gliders for Everyone?

Tags: recursion, cellular-automata

According to [Feynman's Lecture on Computation (Problem 5.1, p. 148 )](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52657907/Feynman-Lectures-on-Computation#scribd) you can extract $E=kTN\log 2$ out of two copies of a random $N$ bit random tape. From this we can conclude that it takes the same ammount of energy to create a copy.

Now assume a fictional two dimensional universe that follows the rule of [Conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life). 
The [gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_%28cellular_automaton%29) then creates copy after copy:

$\hskip2.2in$[image]

Where does the energy come from? Is it possible to show that the initial conditions plus the set of rules create an infinite ammount of gliders?

Comment: It feels like you are trying to force a physical limitation on a Platonistically ideal world of mathematics.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the argument that randomness is energy, but a random string of bits has a lot of _information,_ which makes it harder to compress. An infinite string of gliders, on the other hand, contains only a finite amount of information. (The finite and growing string you actually have contains somewhat more information than that, because you also  have to know where it ends.)

Comment: What is the energy in this model?

Comment: Maybe relevant: the Life-verse isn't time-reversible.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla hmm, maybe filled dots?! I'm not sure...any idea?

Comment: @DavidK the argument can be found in [Feynman's book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52657907/Feynman-Lectures-on-Computation#scribd) on page 148 (165 in the linked pdf)...

Comment: Well, if you don't know what is the energy... what is the sense of asking where does the energy come from?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I relate information to energy like Feynman did...

Comment: In physical world, energy appear to be conserved because of translation invariance in time direction. In this fictional universe, there isn't such a invariance (it is build into the rules of the game), there is no reason to expect anything that behave like energy....

Comment: @achillehui, the Life-verse has translation invariance in time (and in space). The problem is that isn't obvious what can be the energy (or the momentum).

Comment: Quote from *The Theoretical Minimum*: "The rule that dynamical laws must be deterministic and reversible is so central to classical physics that we sometifes forgot to mention it when teaching the subject".

Comment: By any chance related to Cellular Automata by Stephen Wolfram? I have only a hazy understanding.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: although the update rule for Life is time translation invariant, the irreversibility is potentially problematic, as you hint at in an earlier comment.  In particular, the existence of configurations with no predecessor  configuration ([Garden of Eden configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden_(cellular_automaton))) means that there can be a distinguished time origin.  I don't know for certain whether this rules out a Noether's Theorem type result, but it seems like something to worry about.

Comment: It might be better to ask this question first in the context of a reversible cellular automaton, such as [Critters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critters_(block_cellular_automaton)).  Some possibly relevant reading [here](http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~taatis/articles/handbook09.pdf), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_cellular_automaton#Conservation_laws), and [here](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/423457/first-conservation-laws-derived-for-a-virtual-universe/).  (The last of these is a bit overhyped, and, in my opinion, makes too much of the discreteness issue.)

Comment: Thanks again @Will, great stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Your gliders are disappearing at the bottom-right corner, for the law of conservation of mass and the first principle of termodynamics their mass and energy have to be changed in something else.

As long in your universe you have no entropy (it cannot arise from the rules of Life), you will be able to create as much gliders as you want.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the plane is intended to be infinite...

Comment: @Wojowu if it is so, energy is infinite and we have nothing to worry about.

Comment: This is how I see the problem: We start with the glider gun only, and the energy (however we define it) is finite, However, as the time goes, the gun generates more and more gliders, increasing the energy.

Comment: @Wojowu what you think as a moving glider is just a representation of the exited energy states in your universe. As the animated gif has about 20 different images, energy distributes in this universe in only 20 different ways.

Comment: @Wojowu Your views, concerning my infinite universe and your understanding of energy are the same as mine.

Comment: @draks... the plane is just an arrangement of the bits of the Feynman's tape... if it is infinite $N$ is infinite too.